# "No such file or directory" when scp copying Miniconda environment

Tags: linux, command-line, scp

I am trying to copy my Miniconda environment from one server to another server by using the command `scp -r yala-app1:/scratch/houk/miniconda3`. However it returns many similar errors of not being able to find the file to copy such as

```
scp: /scratch/houk/miniconda3/pkgs/python-3.11.4-h955ad1f_0/compiler_compat/ld: No such file or directory
scp: /scratch/houk/miniconda3/pkgs/gcc_impl_linux-64-10.4.0-h7ee1905_17/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/lib/libasan.so.6: No such file or directory
scp: /scratch/houk/miniconda3/envs/pillar2/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/lib/libgfortran.so: No such file or directory
...
```

I did manually verify that all these files exist at the source location. I also tried to check the file types of these files, for example:

```
$ file libgomp.so.1
>> libgomp.so.1: broken symbolic link to `libgomp.so.1.0.0'
```

It seems that all these files that failed during the copy have the property of `broken symbolic link`. How can I fix this issue? Thanks a lot!

Comment: it seems the libgomp.so.1 is a symlink (kind of shortcut file you see in windows) pointing to the actual file libgomp.so.1.0.0 . and libgomp.so.1.0.0 is eventually missing.

find the libgomp.so.1.0.0 and try to fix the broken symlink using ln -s command and then try the sco